# Java: Changing Player

Tags: java

i don't know how to write a Conversion round to change the player Playing

Edit: start with boolean player or while ...

```
import java.util.*;
public class Assignment {
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static int height = 6, width = 6, blank = 0;          //do checkerboard
static int white = 1, black = 2;                      //do player chess
static int[][] board;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    board = new int[height][width];

    board[width / 2-1][height / 2-1] = board[width / 2][height / 2] = 1;
    board[width / 2-1][height / 2] = board[width / 2][height / 2-1] = 2;

    printHead();
    printboard();
    input();
}
    public static void input() {

}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after or what's the actual problem. In general _you_ should try something first and if you run into _specific_ problems you should ask about them here.

Comment: This is quite unclear. What exactly are you asking? How to switch turns in a chess game?

Comment: use boolean player = true; to start and System.out.print("Please enter the position of '" + (player ? 1 : 2) + "': ");

Comment: Okay, so then to switch players, you can write `player = !player;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decide which player is playing you can have a `boolean` variable such as `boolean player1`. Whenever `player1` is true, then it is the first player's turn. When it is false it is the second players turn. In your method after the player is finished you can add the line

```
player1 = !player1;
```

To switch the value of `player1` so that on the next turn your program will know that the player has switched.